# Changing the IP address in the DNS record and then changing it back caused mail-tester.com to complain about no MX record

Tags: domain-name-system, email-server

I have been asked to build a new email server to replace an older one. So for some testing I replaced the IP address of the old server in the DNS A and SPF records for the IP address of the new server. After performing a few test mails I decided to put the old IP address back because the new server isn't fully ready yet.

But now mail-tester.com complains: "We didn't find a mail server (MX Record) behind your domain name mail.domain.com". This never occurred before even though we only used an A record. We had an email expert check our DNS records in the past and he didn't say anything about needing an MX record.

So why did mail-tester.com not complain before I made this change?

We have two email servers that use the same domain and all emails from addresses will be of the format email@domain.com.

This particular server will be sending messages whose reply emails should be going to the other server which already has an MX record, is there a need to have an MX record for this one too?

Answer (score 0):

Sending email from mail server to outside no need MX record, but for receive email from outside you need MX record pointing to your mail server.

If your domain doesn't have an MX record then the process of receiving email will be trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I managed to work it out. The mail command I was using wasn't setting the bounce/return-path header. Thus the return path was being set to root@mail.domain.com and not sender@domain.com.

At first I used:

```
echo "Hi person, This is the message body" | mail -s "This is the subject" -a "FROM: Sender<sender@domain.com>" email@recipient.com
```

But when I changed it to the following it adds a return-path header:

```
echo "Hi person, This is message body" | mail -s "This is the subject"  email@recipient.com -- -f "Sender<sender@domain.com>"
```

Why doesn't the first set both headers? Is there documentation for this which I can read?